# convert minutes to hh/mi/ss format in oracle query

Tags: oracle

I want to know the query which converts minutes to the format of hh/mi/ss in Oracle.I 've already seen lot of same questions from many forums but  nothing helped me to get the exact result.

The query I used -Select to_char(to_date(mod(100,60),'mi'),'hh/mi/ss') from dual;
But I don't know how to get the hour value.Because mod function returns only the remainder I don't know how to take the quotient part and substitute into the hour field.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  Show an example.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the datatype of the field containing the "minutes" value. Thanks.

Comment: You need to explain how and why those other answers failed to help you.  Otherwise we might replicate those same answers, wasting our time and yours.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there are two ways of storing "minutes" in an Oracle database - you can either store them in a field whose datatype is `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`, or you can store them in a `NUMBER`. The simplest case to handle is the `INTERVAL` - in this case, the `TO_CHAR` function converts the value to a string of the form `SDD HH:MM:SS.FFFFFF`, where 'S' is sign ('+' or '-' as intervals can be positive or negative), `DD` = days, `HH`= hours, 'MM' = minutes, 'SS' = seconds, and 'FFFFFF' = fractions; thus, to get the `HH:MI:SS` all we need to do is use the `SUBSTR` function, as in

```
SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(I_VAL), 5, 8)
```

where `I_VAL` is an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` value.

If the value to be converted is in a numeric field it gets a bit messy as we have to compute the individual field values, then subtract the previous fields as part of getting the next field. However, since the value stored is in minutes instead of seconds it's not particularly difficult:

```
create table TST (N_VAL  NUMBER,
                  I_VAL  INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND);

INSERT INTO TST(N_VAL, I_VAL) VALUES (666, INTERVAL '666' MINUTE);

SELECT N_VAL, 
       TRUNC(N_VAL/60) AS HOURS,
       N_VAL-(TRUNC(N_VAL/60) * 60) AS MINUTES,
       0 AS SECONDS,
       TO_CHAR(I_VAL),
       SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(I_VAL), 5, 8) AS HMS_FROM_INTERVAL
  FROM TST;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/14174d/3)

Best of luck.